# Sql - query taking long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is called `map_life`, and the second one is called `scripts`. The `map_life` table has a lot of rows, that are identified by a column called `lifeid`. The rows at the table `scripts` are identified by the column `objectid`. I want to create a query that gets all the rows from the table `map_life` and also adds the column `script`from `scripts` table if `lifeid`matches `objectid`, and that the `objecttype` is `npc`.

I created the following query.

```
SELECT id
    ,lifeid
    ,x_pos
    ,y_pos
    ,foothold
    ,min_click_pos
    ,max_click_pos
    ,respawn_time
    ,flags
    ,script.script
FROM map_life life
LEFT JOIN scripts script 
    ON script.objectid = life.lifeid 
        AND script.script_type = 'npc'
```

However, that query takes **a lot** of time. Any way I can tune it? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have ran EXPLAIN command, there are the results.

```
    "id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
1,"SIMPLE","life","ALL","","","","",47600,""
1,"SIMPLE","script","ref","PRIMARY","PRIMARY","1","const",1834,"Using where"
```

**EDIT 2:** Here are the create statmenets of each table.

```
map_life

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mcdb`.`map_life`;
CREATE TABLE  `mcdb`.`map_life` (
  `id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mapid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `life_type` enum('npc','mob','reactor') NOT NULL,
  `lifeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `life_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'For reactors, specifies a handle so scripts may interact with them; for NPC/mob, this field is useless',
  `x_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `foothold` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `min_click_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_click_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `respawn_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` set('faces_left') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`lifeid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetype` (`mapid`,`life_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47557 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

scripts

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mcdb`.`scripts`;
CREATE TABLE  `mcdb`.`scripts` (
  `script_type` enum('npc','reactor','quest','item','map','map_enter','map_first_enter') NOT NULL,
  `helper` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT 'Represents the quest state for quests, and the index of the script for NPCs (NPCs may have multiple scripts).',
  `objectid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `script` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`script_type`,`helper`,`objectid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Lists all the scripts that belong to NPCs/reactors/etc. ';
```

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN ...` and see what it tells you.  This will you which indexes (if any) it's using.  That should help you speed it up.

Comment: make sure you have some indexes on objectid and lifeid.  Also, find the EXECUTION PLAN for more hints

Comment: Your query seems to be reading all rows instead of using an index before arriving at result. The most probable reason is lack of index on primary keys on both tables.

Comment: @Shailendra The table `scripts` has `script_type` and `objectid` has primary keys. The table `map_life` has `id` as primary key, but it's not used, only for indexing. Should I set `objectid` as the primary key?

Comment: There is only one primary key and that should depend on the domain (for business key) or simply a surrogate key. However the idea is to have index on the columns being used for join on both tables. As suggested by others you can run EXPLAIN and interpret the result. That would give you more insight. That would tell you even how many rows would be scanned to arrive at the result.

Comment: @Shailendra I've ran the Explain command and updated the main post. I'm sorry, but I'm new to Sql. I don't see how these values help me.

Comment: For the "life" table "ALL" means full table scan which is bad http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types

Comment: Can you provide the full DDL for each of the tables? Knowing which columns in the select list come from which table, and also their data types will be helpful. Also what percentage of the records in `scripts ` have a `script_type = 'npc'`?

Comment: Also, we need to see the indexes. Providing the `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table will show what we need.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I uploaded the create statements for all the tables.

Comment: Great, I provided an answer.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com is an excellent introduction to indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add an index to the 'script_type' field depending on the type.  If it's not using a type that can be indexed, you should change the type if possible and index

Here is a link that discusses more about indexes with MySQL, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: The field `script_type` is indexed, and so it the field `objectid`. In the `map_life` table, only the field `id` is indexed, but that field is not used. Should I index `lifeid` as well?

Comment: That should be indexed as well.  In my experience it's typically the string fields that slow things down so that's what I keyed in on but anything used in those joins should be indexed to get the max speed.  You have almost everything indexed so hopefully it's just this one last piece.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key on `scripts` is:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`script_type`,`helper`,`objectid`)
```

The order of multi-column keys is important.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html):

> Any index that does not span all AND levels in the WHERE clause is not
>   used to optimize the query. In other words, to be able to use an
>   index, a prefix of the index must be used in every AND group.

Your primary key on scripts does include both the `script_type` and `objectid` columns, which are both used in the join's `ON` clause:

```
ON script.objectid = life.lifeid 
    AND script.script_type = 'npc'
```

but the primary key also includes the `helper` column between those two, so MySQL can only use the primary key index for searching using the first column (`script_type`).

So, for every join, MySQL must search through all `scripts` records where `script_type` is 'npc' to find the particular `objectid` record to join on.

MySQL could full utilize the primary key index if your `ON` clause included all three columns like this:

```
ON script.objectid = life.lifeid
    AND script.helper = 1
    AND script.script_type = 'npc'
```

If you often query the `scripts` table without specifying the `helper` column, consider changing the order of the columns in the primary key to put the `helper` column last:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`script_type`,`objectid`,`helper`)
```

Then, your original `ON` clause is appropriate for the index because the index prefix includes all of the columns in your predicate (`script_type`,`objectid`):

```
ON script.objectid = life.lifeid 
    AND script.script_type = 'npc'
```

Alternatively, add an additional index with just the two columns mentioned in the `ON` clause:

```
KEY `scrypt_type_objectid` (`script_type`,`objectid`)
```